# how can I ask a map whether a popup is open and which it is

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, leaflet

I am developing a map for botanic garden, I'm using leaflet, bootstrap, jQuery, getting inspiration (aka: selective copying, demolishing and pasting) from http://users.leafletjs.com. my experiments are to be found at http://cuchubo.wikidot.com/virtual-tour-2.

one of my buttons is for searching plants similar to others.

once the user opens a popup (with information about a plant), she might want to hit the search button and she will be surprised if the plant shown in the popup is not preselected in the search field.

I can check whether there's an open popup with

```
map._popup != null
```

but I suppose that the leading underscore is trying to tell me something!

how would you people do this? I mean: the map *knows* which popup is open, why should I write half a line of code to keep track of it myself too?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but you can listen to the `popupopen` event on the map: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-popupopen.

Comment: I don't think you are missing anything, I'm just starting using these frameworks and I always assume frameworks already contain more than I need! so you suggest I program the logic myself, isn't it?